# Wanted to create the Lambda layer having the Dependencies size of 200 Mb through AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I am working in the project where I need to attach the AWS layer to the lambda function. The Dependencies size is more than the 200 MB. Should I need to make the zip file then upload them in the s3 bucket and then make the layer from them through AWS CDK or I can directly make the lambda layer without using the s3 bucket through the AWS CDK.

Right now I have manually created the zip file then upload it to the s3 bucket then made the layer through it. Now I want to do this from CDK.

Answer (score 0):

The CDK uploads file assets to the S3 Bucket it created during [bootstrapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html).  The CDK zips and uploads assets to S3 when you `cdk deploy` your app.

Your job is to  tell the [LayerVersion](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.LayerVersion.html) construct where to find your code:

```js
const layer = new lambda.LayerVersion(stack, 'MyLayer', {
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, 'layer-code')),
  compatibleRuntimes: [lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_LATEST],
});
```

The Lambda deployment package size [quota](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html) is 250 MB (unzipped).

Comment: Thanks it really helped. Successfully implemented.